How to only enrich sensible GO and KEGG terms?
I'm thinking of analyzing enriched pathways using KEGG and GO databases on de-novo assembled transcripts using clusterProfiler 4.0. After annotating them with eggnog-mapper, I have some annotated and some unannotated Transcripts. Here is the doubt:
I'm only interested in pathways and ontologies that make sense (Like "Lipid Biosynthesis" or "Antibiotic degradation", not like "Metabolic process" or "Cytosol"). So I was thinking, after getting the p-values (not adjusted yet), I will only do post-hoc analysis for gene groups I care about.

Is this strategy sound?
Can it be automated somehow? because the list of ontologies and KEGG modules is so long? Because I heard somewhere that there is a parent-child graph-like relationship among GO terms. Also, a recent update in clusterProfiler 4.0 performs this analysis on KEGG modules, but I don't know how to deal with the useless portion of GO terms.

Thanks for your kind help.
